# Почему элемент добавляется не в тот список Python

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Файл 1 (модуль):

```
class Page:
def step(self):
    print('Лала')

children = list()
# parent = str()
# name = str()
# numbering = str()
# func = step

def __init__(self, numbering, parent, name='Страница', func=step):
    self.parent = parent
    self.name = name
    self.numbering = numbering
    self.func = func

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def add_children(self, name, func=step):
    new_numb = str(len(self.children))
    a = Page(numbering=new_numb, parent=self.numbering, name=name, func=func)
    self.children.append(a)
```

Файл 2 (основной код):

```
from SNmenu import *

menu = Page(name='menu', numbering='0', parent=None)
menu.add_children(name='Страница 1')
menu.add_children(name='Страница 2')
menu.add_children(name='Страница 3')
menu.add_children(name='Страница 4')
menu.children[0].add_children(name='Страница 1.1')
menu.children[0].add_children(name='Страница 1.2')
menu.children[1].add_children(name='Страница 2.1')
menu.children[2].add_children(name='Страница 3.1')

if menu.children == menu.children[0].children:
    print('Списки одинаковы')
```

Я хочу чтобы код работал вот так:
[image: Картинка 1]

Но код работает так:
[image: Картинка 2]

Answer (score 3):

```
class Page:
    children = list()
```

Так перенесите `children = list()` в `__init__` и сделайте его полем *экземпляра* класса. Тогда у каждого экземпляра класса `Page` будет свой список страниц:

```
def __init__(self, numbering, parent, name='Страница', func=step):
    self.children = list()
    ...
```

Сейчас у вас `children` является полем класса и инициализируется один раз - при создании класса, и все экземпляры класса работают с `self.children` как с одним и тем же списком `Page.children` по факту. Просто когда создаётся экземпляр класса, он получает себе все поля, которые есть у класса и работает дальше с ними как со своими полями.